# how does omniauth intercept /auth/facebook in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am trying to learn the insides of omniauth and am curious as to how it knows to intercept /auth/facebook url.  Does it append to the existing routes file?  Where can I find the insides of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses a rack middleware to sniff the path that's being requested, and if it matches, calls the associated strategy. The files in question are [`lib/omniauth.rb`](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/lib/omniauth.rb) and [`lib/omniauth/strategy.rb`](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb).

To see the path taken, start at the [`call!`](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb#L165) method in `strategy.rb`. Pay special attention to anything checking for `path_prefix`, which defaults to `/auth`.